# Math riddle from Math Olympiad

Tags: java, math, recursion, backtracking

Determine all triples (a, b, c) of positive integers such that each of the numbers: ab-c, bc-a, ca-b is a power of two.

How to solve this with backtracking? Tried but have not succeed..

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356164/finding-a-b-c-with-ab-c-bc-a-and-ca-b-being-powers-of-2

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder how you can use backtracking (recursion) to find these answers :)

Comment: Show what you have *tried*

Comment: Just because you say "I want to solve this with backtracking" doesn't mean it's a good idea or even possible.  Math contest problems are generally made to be easily solvable once you look at it just the right way.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I just wanted to know how to implement the "stupid way" to solve this kind of problem.. (trying all the different possibilities)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the EXACT definition of the problem, you can't solve it algorithmically (at least, not in a "dummy" way like backtracking or brute force) because you don't know the range of your a,b,c parameters: all you know is that they are positive integers, but those are infinite!

If you were told: a,b,c are all lower than, say, 10^6, then you could do something like:

```
int limit = Math.pow(10, 6);
for (int a=1; a<=limit; a++) {
  for (int b=1; b<=limit; b++) {
    for (int c=1; c<=limit; c++) {
      if (CONDITION_IS_MET) {
        solutions.add(a, b, c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where condition is met tests for all the combinations to be powers of two. You can test if a number is a power of two by counting the number of 1's in its binary representation: if it's exactly 1 (or 0), it's a power of two:

```
boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
  String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
  int count = 0;
  for (char c: binary.toCharArray()) {
    count+= c=='1' ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return count<=1;
}
```

Given it comes from a math Olympics, probably there is some way to write down the problem as a system of equations or similar relations that will give you the answer. Have you tried that?

Comment: Let's say we assume a,b,c are maximum 10 (each of them.. as base case). Is it still possible? Using 3 additional integers as the powers (2^x,2^y,2^z)

Comment: @DanielWatson it's been two days, does my answer satisfy you or not? If yes, can you accept it and close this? If not, do you need further info?